# How to utilise multiple values from a single shortcode attribute?

Tags: shortcode, array

i.e [test somevalues=1,2,3,4,5]

First time poster and alsoa  php newb, I'm trying to add a feature to a plugin but I seem to keep triggering a debug notice from wordpress.

```
$somearray = shortcode_atts([
               'somevalues' => null,
    ], $atts);
$somearray['somevalues'] = array_map( 'trim', str_getcsv( $somearray['somevalues'], ',' ) );
```

The above does work, but it results in a debug Notice: **wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly**.

Is there a way to achieve the same without triggering the notice? It doesn't have to be csv, I just need it to return a string of somevalues, rather than returning an int. I guess what I want it to act like is as if it was written like [test somevalues=one,two,three,four,five]

Edit: Found original stack post from 3 years ago which is exactly what I'm trying to achieve [Retrieve multiple values passed to a single attribute in a shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269656/retrieve-multiple-values-passed-to-a-single-attribute-in-a-shortcode?rq=1)

Any suggestions on how to get around this?
Many thanks

Comment: Please show your full code, it's not possible to see how that error is triggered, in the code you have shared.

Comment: So you're just asking how to convert the string "1,2,3,4,5" into an array by splitting the string on commas?

Comment: I'll see to sharing a large chunk of code or a fully working demo piece. @Rup, yes something like that, the issue I'm facing is if I leave the input to somevalues from the shortcode as is a user can put in 1,2,3 but the array will only see the first value 1 and discard the rest due it treating the key as an int.

Comment: This might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42526/7968 and I guess you based your code from here:https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/269660/7968 which seems to be a working example, so I would read that again carefully.

Comment: @Q Studio, Thank you, you prompted me to go and check line for line took hours, I was passing multiple arguments to $args within a single attribute that turned out to be part of another plugin which was causing the notice, I changed the key in $args and it stopped, so it was a conflict.